# Was "Assassin's Creed" based on the 1907 book "Lord of the World"?

Tags: assassins-creed

Was *Assassin's Creed* based on the 1907 book [*Lord of the World*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_of_the_World) by Robert Hugh Benson in any way?

It's like *Assassin's Creed* but the opposite where the Freemasons won instead and shows how the assassins would rule the world in a bad way also.

Answer (score 13):

An interview with the game's producer, Jade Raymond would suggest that the primary inspiration was a book called *[Alamut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alamut_(Bartol_novel))*, written in 1938 by Vladimir Bartol. The game also has shades of Prince of Persia, but mostly stylistic touches rather than in terms of plotline.

> **Q: Is it true that the game was originally titled Prince of Persia Assassins, and was going to be part of the POP universe?**
>
> **Jade Raymond:** *I've had a few people ask me this and I'm not sure where the rumour came from. Assassins is being developed by the Prince of Persia team in Montreal but was never intended to be part of that series. Instead of using Arabian legends we decided to take inspiration from a book called Alamut, by the Slovenian writer Vladimir Bartol.*
>
> **Q. Is the game's focus stealth like Splinter Cell or action like Prince of Persia?**
>
> **Jade Raymond:** *Our goal with this game is to deliver completely next-gen gameplay, so the team set the bar where no game has gone before. I really wouldn't call it a stealth game because it's much more focused on fast-paced action. The only stealth element is the social stealth where you use the crowds to disguise yourself, but we've steered clear of the traditional rules of stealth games like hiding in shadows or sneaking around corners. That's not really what Assassin's Creed is striving for at all.*
>
> **Q. Why did you set the game during the Crusades?**
>
> **Jade Raymond:** *In the book Alamut, the Assassins are a historical clan that came to be during the Crusades. And in terms of gameplay and game structure, we could see the Crusades would work really well. You have all kinds of narrow streets that are great for bustling crowds, and lots of complicated architectural details that makes for interesting level design. And also you have this time that's filled with a lot of warfare and drama.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview: Producer Jade Raymond tells us why Assassin's Creed is not just a game, but a crusade to revolutionise a genre](https://web.archive.org/web/20121025102806/http://www.computerandvideogames.com/148805/interviews/assassins-creed/)</sup></sub>